# Typescript app and api on heroku - CORS failed and NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, heroku

I have been looking for a solution on this for days now and getting pretty tired of it. Here is my setup on heroku:

**Application**

- Running an app with typescript served by Heroku.
  For log in and connection with my api this code is used in my layout screen:

LoginScreen.js

```
import useMutation from "../../../../core/hooks/useMutation";
import logo from "../../../../img/logo.svg";
import { useAuthContext } from "../AuthProvider";
import useForm from "../../../../core/hooks/useForm";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Label from "../../../Design/Form/Label";
import Input from "../../../Design/Form/Input";
import "../login/styles/auth.css";
import errorHandler from "../../../../core/helpers/errorHandler";

// validation schema
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
});

const defaultData = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { login } = useAuthContext();
  const { isLoading, error, mutate } = useMutation();
  const { values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(schema, {
    ...defaultData,
  });

  // handle submit
  const handleData = (values) => {
    mutate(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      data: values,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        login(data);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="auth">
      <div id="auth-login">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        <h2>Aanmelden:</h2>
        <form
          className="auth-form"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleData)}
          noValidate
        >
          {error && <div className="error">{errorHandler(error)}</div>}
          <div className="form-item">
            <Label htmlFor="email" className="auth-label">
              Gebruikersnaam of e-mail:
            </Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              className="auth-input"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.email}
              error={errors.email}
              disabled={isLoading}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-item">
            <Label htmlFor="password" className="auth-label">
              Wachtwoord:
            </Label>
            <Input
              className="auth-input"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              error={errors.password}
              disabled={isLoading}
            />
          </div>
          <button>Inloggen</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

- Authentication with API goes through this code:

useAuthApi.js

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "../../components/App/Auth/AuthProvider";
import ApiError from "../error/ApiError";
import AppError from "../error/AppError";
import { handleErrors } from "../helpers/api";

const useAuthApi = () => {
  const { auth, logout } = useAuthContext();

  const authFetch = useCallback(
    (url, config = {}) => {
      // add authorization header
      if (auth && auth.token) {
        config.headers = {
          ...(config.headers || {}),
          Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
        };
      }

      return fetch(url, config)
        .then(handleErrors)
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error instanceof ApiError) {
            if (error.isUnauthorized()) {
              logout();
            }
            throw error;
          } else {
            throw new AppError(error);
          }
        });
    },
    [logout, auth]
  );

  return {
    authFetch,
  };
};

export default useAuthApi;
```

- local .env, which is not copied to heroku. On heroku I use the same variables, but I put them in my Config Vars

.env

```
REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3002
```

I changed localhost with the correct url of what Heroku gives me.

**API**

- Running my typescript API on PORT 3002. I am in doubt about this port, because if I deploy in Heroku, I get following output: App has started on http://localhost:54400

index.ts

```
import "dotenv/config";

import * as express from "express";
import { AppDataSource } from "./database/DatabaseSource";
import { registerErrorHandler, registerMiddleware } from "./middleware";
import { registerRoutes } from "./routes";

// initialize database
AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    const app = express();

    // middleware
    registerMiddleware(app);

    // routes
    registerRoutes(app);

    // error handler
    registerErrorHandler(app);

    // start express server
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3002);

    if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
      console.log(`App has started on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

const closeApp = () => {
  // properly close database
  AppDataSource.destroy();
  // finish Node process
  process.exit();
};

process.on("SIGINT", () => closeApp());
process.on("SIGTERM", () => closeApp());
```

- local .env, yet again these settings are configured in Config Vars on Heroku itself

.env

```
PORT=3002
ENV=production
DB_HOST=heroku-database
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=heroku-user
DB_PASSWORD=heroku-password
DB_NAME=heroku-name
DATABASE_URL=heroku-url
JWT_SECRET=sometoken
JWT_EXPIRES_IN_HOURS=24
PGSSLMODE=no-verify
PORT=3002
PROCFILE=./Procfile
```

- Using CORS-middleware, which I have been trying to change already many times. Right now, this is my code for the middleware:

index.ts

```
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as helmet from "helmet";
import { QueryFailedError, TypeORMError } from "typeorm";
import BaseError from "../errors/BaseError";
import { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";

const registerMiddleware = (app: Router) => {
  // use CORS middleware
  // add "allow all" cors
  if (process.env.ENV === "PRODUCTION" || process.env.ENV === "production") {
    const corsOptions = {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET','POST','DELETE','UPDATE','PUT','PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
      credentials: true,
    };
    // allows CORS online
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  } else {
    app.use(cors());
  }
  // JSON is going to be the default format
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
    })
  );
  // blocks the browser from trying to guess the MIME type
  app.use(helmet.noSniff());
  // Hides the X-Powered-By header
  app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
  // Adds a filter to prevent XSS attacks
  app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
};

// Error handler
const registerErrorHandler = (app: Application) => {
  // Default error handler
  app.use(function (
    err: Error,
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ) {
    let message: string;
    let statusCode: number;
    let errors = {};

    if (err instanceof QueryFailedError) {
      message = err.driverError.detail;
      statusCode = 400;
    } else if (err instanceof TypeORMError) {
      message = err.message;
      statusCode = 500;
    } else if (err instanceof BaseError) {
      message = err.message;
      statusCode = err.statusCode;
      errors = err.errors;
    } else {
      message = String(err);
      statusCode = 500;
    }
    res.status(statusCode).json({
      message,
      statusCode,
      errors,
    });
  });
};

export { registerMiddleware, registerErrorHandler };
```

- And finally creating my database and setting my dbsource.

databaseSource.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import all different entities

// config for the database
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "postgres",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: [
    all tables needed
  ],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [],
  // ssl:
  //   process.env.ENV === "PRODUCTION"
  //     ? {
  //         rejectUnauthorized: false,
  //       }
  //     : false,
});
```

I did put ssl-part in comment because otherwise I would get a **FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ... no encryption** error

**Error handling**
Trying to log in, I get following errors:

- My code gets stuck on the useAuthApi.js file to return my fetch. I suppose this is because the connection to my postgres (also hosted by heroku) is failing? With this fetch, the browser gives back a **CORS failed** error. When trying the same code using CorsE extension, nothing changes.
- Next error is in POST method. I end up with an NS_ERROR_BAD_DOM_URI error which results in failing to login without any other error code.

If I run both, API and APP, locally there does not seem to be a problem ...
Can someone guide me in the right direction? Been trying many things about CORS changes already, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

My same error was that the second postgres process remained in the background.

Check out these options:

- Option 1: Stop the PostgreSQL service on Windows
- Option 2 (using WSL): Completely uninstall Protgres 12 from Windows and install postgresql-client on WSL (sudo apt install postgresql-client-common postgresql-client libpq-dev)
- Option 3: Change the port of the docker container

I found them [here](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/issues/112#issuecomment-579712540).